# Preprocessing ASP.NET MVC Razor views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to do some preprocessing on my views before they are parsed by the Razor template engine. The only way I found so far is by extending the `RazorTemplateEngine` class and overriding the `CreateParser` method, where I can return a custom parser that does the preprocessing before calling the base parser.

Now my problem is - how can I make Razor use my custom template engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that will work for you but it should :) 
try to add

```
@inherits YourRazorTemplateEngine
```

in the head of your views.

for more information look at [this page](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications)

Comment: I'm looking at TemplateEngine, not ViewEngine.

Comment: System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine

Comment: Sorry I've got miss understanding I'll Update my answer